# Inadequate support for comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have just come from the hell of writing [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447000/perl-changes-to-array-not-persisting#comment41545425_26447000), and as I have had numerous problems in the past with formatting comments nicely I thought I would write about them

- There seems to be no documentation for the variation of markdown and HTML that is available within comments
- HTML seems to be unavailable within comments, although I can't see why it should be that way and I have done no real tests on this.
- There is no *preview* option on comments. So I have to bare my inadequacies to the world before I get the debug information to fix them myself. For a site with such elaborate posting facilities, this is a surprising shortfall
- Explicit newlines in comments please. I realise that it would take some fancy JavaScript, but at present there is *no way* to politely publish multi-line code in Stack Overflow comments
- And, while we're at it, the five-minute limit on updating comments seems to be a wrong decision. If I find a mistake later than five minutes after my post then I simply edit and copy my original, then delete it and repost

What does the team think?

Comment: Downvote is not mine, but I stopped at your first bullet point because that documentation is rightly available in the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). Pretty much all your other points are also answered on the [Overmeta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) if you dig around a little.

Comment: I downvoted because I disagree with the feature request. Documentation is available, there's a link to it right next to the comment entry box. As for the rest, comments are second class posts and aren't likely - and probably don't need - to get much more support or features than they already do.

Comment: All of that is fair, but @AnthonyGrist I wonder if you've ever had to describe what is missing from a Stack Overflow question without submitting a *solution*?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Thank you. That is invaluable. But can you trace a stream of information from the comment box to "what I should put i here"? Also, your reference doesn't seem to solve the rest of my points.

Comment: @Borodin, I'm afraid I don't understand your "stream of information" part of your comment... Can you rephrase it? As for your last sentence, it means you have not dug around enough :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: What I'm asking is, how can someone typing into a comment box know what he may type? It shouldn't be by referring to the Site Manual

Comment: @Borodin, ah, I see. You might have missed the `help` link to the bottom right of the comment area, below the Add Comment button. It pops up a short explanation with a `Learn more...` link leading to the full help page.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Yes, thank you. I had become accustomed to the furniture of the SO page and ignored it. So help for comments is a click at bottom-right on `help`, while help for questions and solutions is a click on an orange question mark icon at top right. Not a nice design. And we still haven't solved my problem of multi-line comments that *must* exist as they are not a solution.

Comment: Because of comments like *"I stopped at your first bullet point"* I think I must post many, separate questions here.

Comment: @Borodin, *or* you could follow my advice and consult the Overmeta. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-about-newlines-within-comments), I found the discussion regarding multi-line comments for you.

Answer (score 4):

The first premise is false:

> - There seems to be no documentation for the variation of markdown and HTML that is available within comments

[**editing-help#comment-formatting**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

> - HTML

What for? `<img>`?

> - Preview

Just hit enter, review, edit.

> - Newlines

Use some form of spacing `. . . . .` or write an answer if the thing is so extensive.

> - Time limit

Yes, is a good workaround when spotting mistakes after the time limit: copy/delete/create-new-one.

---

Related:

- [**How do comments work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/185667)

---

Of interest:

> ### [Add keyboard shortcuts to comments](https://stackapps.com/q/2103/10590)
>
> *This script adds <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (bold), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (italic), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (code), and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (link) shortcuts to comments.*
>
> ### [Disable enter for submitting comments](https://stackapps.com/q/2061/10590)
>
> *This user script disables the default behavior of the <kbd>enter</kbd> key [submitting a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/63303/why-can-you-type-new-lines-in-comments-if-they-are-never-rendered). With this script installed, you must explicitly click the Add Comment button to submit your comment.*

Comment: Regarding your first point: for example, I would like to be able to put ***bold italics*** within *italics*. That is a problem with *markdown*, but can usually be fixed by using `<b>` tags. The current implementation requires that the italics be closed and followed by whitespace before the bold italics are opened.

Comment: I agree with the premise being wrong, however I just fell into comment hell myself because there is no preview for comments.  So I tried adding a short code snippet. Tried again. ... and again and then fell onto "you can only edit a comment every 5 seconds".  Plus the default behavior of a comment is to post upon hitting the enter key, unlike when posting an answer.