# Why comments have so many format limitations

Tags: discussion, comments

In some situations I would like to post a comment that is not strictly an answer but still need some formatting or code inside. But comments have no way to format code. Also, there aren't (if am i right) no line breaks in comments, which make them more difficult to write and read.

Is there an explicit reason to not allow complex and well formatted comments?

Comment: Some past requests for additional comment features: [1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274820/inadequate-support-for-comments) [2 (overmeta)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/add-syntax-highlighting-and-line-breaks-to-comment-formatting) [3 (overmeta)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/can-we-enable-syntax-highlighting-for-code-in-comments) [4 (overmeta)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6407/allow-html-tags-in-comments/28523#28523)

Comment: Also if you need more space, you can always [create a gist](https://gist.github.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some sites on the network **do** allow more complex forms of comments. They allow MathJax, and you can create a comment like this:

> [image]

Our site, however, does not have a lot of content that would need MathJax, (and most likely people would end up not using it, or having it mess up their formatting inadvertently), especially in the comments.

The other thing is *why would you write long and complex comments in the first place*? If you have an answer, use the answer box. Otherwise, reconsider why you are writing the comment ... would a link do instead?

Comments are not where you write the things you want to be immortalized; they are the place for quick scrawls of marginalia. Comments are already noisy enough, so it's not beneficial to give them prominence over the important things: questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are meant to be ephemeral tho. Allowing "in-depth" code in one would defeat the purpose. [From the comments privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

> What are comments?
>
> **Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.** They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. **There's no revision history**, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.

Answer (score 1):

Comments aren't really meant to be that complex, as previously established.  But I'd like to emphasize a specific point you made:

> ...I would like to post a comment that is not strictly an answer...

**Comments aren't answers**, and even though a lot of people do use them as such (I'm guilty of this on occasion as well), you really should consider answering the question outright if you have an answer for it as opposed to commenting.  Reserve comments for gaining insight into what the OP is asking or clarifying a constraint as opposed to an impromptu way to answer a question.